# update-grub ignoring GRUB_GFXMODE only

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, resolution, grub2-mkconfig

I uncommented `/etc/default/grub` and changed to following:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=2560x1440x32
```

Then, ran `sudo update-grub` without issues.

Now, the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` still contains:

```
...
if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=1280x720,1280x800,auto
  load_video
...
```

As expected, the resolution was 1280x720.

Before someone asks:

1. I didn't touch `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` so far. Only `cat`ed it.
2. Modifying any other variable like `GRUB_TIMEOUT` in works correctly.
3. 2560x1440 instead of 2560x1440x32 didn't work either.
4. Adding `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` in `/etc/default/grub` got updated in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` didn't help.
5. 2560x1440 is my native resolution as confirmed by xrandr and works fine. grub also is fine with it as evident below.

The only thing that currently works is modifying `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` on previously mentioned line:

```
...
if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=2560x1440x32,auto
  load_video
...
```

**TLDR:** update-grub ignores GRUB_GFXMODE when it's updating `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Is there a way to get verbose output when running `update-grub`?
I am on kali-linux/Debian dual booted with Windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution just now by running:

```
grep -rni "1280x720,1280x800,auto" / 2>/dev/null
```

which gave:

```
/etc/default/grub.d/kali-themes.cfg:2:GRUB_GFXMODE="1280x720,1280x800,auto"
```

Commenting this `GRUB_GFXMODE` line in `/etc/default/grub.d/kali-themes.cfg` worked.